# Change Primary Image in Array of Images

Tags: javascript

I have several images on my page that I use a jQuery scroller to scroll through the thumbnail images.  The scrolling portion of my site works just fine.  The problem comes in when I try to click on a thumbnail to set it as the "primary" large image.  The code I am using works in Firefox but not in IE.  Here is the code for the primary and thumb images:

```
      <a href="/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080202.jpg" id="vehicle-primary" data-lightbox="vehicle-photos" class="primary"><img src="/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080202.jpg" class="primary-img" name="vehicle-primary" /></a>
      <a href="/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080218.jpg" id="vehicle-primary" data-lightbox="vehicle-photos" class="hidden"><img src="/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080218.jpg" class="primary-img" name="vehicle-primary" /></a>

      <div class="slider1">
        <div class="slide"><a href="#" onclick="viewVehicle('vehicle-primary','/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080202.jpg'); return false"><img src="/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080202.jpg"></a></div>
        <div class="slide"><a href="#" onclick="viewVehicle('vehicle-primary','/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080218.jpg'); return false"><img src="/vehicle-uploads/31596/20150109_080218.jpg"></a></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="/vehicle-uploads/upload-vehicle.gif"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="/vehicle-uploads/upload-vehicle.gif"></div>
      </div>
```

I am using a javascript function to change the primary image:

```
function viewVehicle(name,src) {
    if (document.images) {
            document.images[name].src = src;
    }
    document.getElementById(name).href = src;
    return false;
}
```

I need to change the primary image src to the src of the thumbnail, and I am controlling which image is showing by using a "primary" class vs. "hidden" class.  I hope I explained this enough to understand.

You can view an example here:

http://www.upcars.com/find-vehicle/vehicle-details.asp?v_id=31596

Comment: none of your images have ids so getElementById shouldn't be expected to find anything

Comment: they dont have names either

Comment: Actually, his function is referencing the ids of the first two anchor tags, which are identical and should be unique.